# Load huge dataset from cloud in my ListView - Android

Tags: android, listview, cloud

I have read a lot of SO answers asking a similar question, but I believe my question is different. I have to load around **70-80K** records from the cloud and display it to the user in a `ListView`. A few things that I want to be done :

1. I don't want to use a load more `Button` or load more objects when the user scrolls as I have a index from A-Z so the user could start my application and click on Z and the data should be present/available to him.
2. I have considered pre fetching the data using a splash screen but I was wondering if there is really any other optimised  method to fetch such huge data.
3. I don't want to hang up the UI thread with the Loading progress bar.

I agree that this may be too much to ask for but I am just trying to see if someone has a very efficient way of doing this. I am open to ideas involving modifications in the backend on web service as well, so if you have an efficient way of achieving this using some modifications on the web service, that is also fine for me.

If it helps, look at your default contacts app, it has all the data ready and available to you when you open it. You can directly use the index to navigate to Z section. Just assume the same with 70k entries in the app.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best solutions I figured out with the help of Tamal Mukherjee and Roman Nurik.

Tamal's solution :

Just load 5-10 rows/letter. Add a 'more' button or handle scroll event and load dynamically. Use SQLite to store data. Use background threads to fill up the db. ﻿

Roman Nurik's soltuion :

With 80k rows, that's well over 1000 items per letter in the alphabet. Seems like you'll need a lot more than letter indexing to make this UI usable. Why not offer filter-as-you-type? That'll result in more HTTP requests but might result in a better UX.﻿

So i guess my implementation will be a combination of the both.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this step:-

1- Call API on splashscreen using `IntentService`.

2- Use **static** broadCasting and save API response into sqlitedb using ORMLite in `onRecieve()` method of `BroadCastReciever`.

3- Make sure there should be separate class for receiver.

4- Use Loader Manager for updating `ListView`.